# express.js session using other files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, model-view-controller, session-cookies

I've create a project that selling game point on the web with expressjs+mongoose+mongodb. my project has folder like this:

> - [in "view" folder(homepage.ejs - game.ejs - login.ejs - signup.ejs)],
> - [in "controller" folder(homepageCtrl.js - gameCtrl.js - loginCtrl.js - signupCtrl.js)] and
> - [in "routes" folder(homepageRtr.js - gameRtr.js - loginRtr.js - signupRtr.js)].

In main page I create index.js. I can connect database, CRUD and etc. but I cant do anything with sessions. I install express-sesssion from npmjs. But I cant use it in all folders. I can only use in index.js file which my main node.js file. How can I use it in every files? I dont add any require or lib to the other page's top that I want to use session. Should I? which require or lib statement should I add to the top of other page except index.js file.

Comment: Assuming you have configured `express-session` properly, you should be able to access session from request eg. `req.session`. Here is a nice and straightforward tutorial https://codeforgeek.com/2014/09/manage-session-using-node-js-express-4/

Comment: ok, but I dont add any require or lib to the other page that I want to use session. Should I? which require or lib statement should I add to the top of other page except index.js file

Comment: Let nodejs runtime answers that

Comment: Im sorry? @YohanesGultom I didnt understand.

Comment: My bad. Short answer to your previous question is "no". But asking a question that can be answered by writing and try running a code (in other word: asking the runtime) is not a good gesture

Comment: @YohanesGultom  when I use or create any session on other controller files I take a error like that **TypeError: Cannot set property 'my_session_name' of undefined.** my code is in loginCtrl.js is:

Comment: `mySchema.find({username: usernameS, password: passwordS}).find(function(err, result) {
  if (result[0]!=null) {
   req.session.my_session_name=usernameS;
   console.log("LOGIN IS SUCCES!! ");
  }else{
   console.log("ERROR!");
  }
  });`

Comment: Can you reduce your code to a minimal complete verifiable example and put it in the question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself. I write for other friends who have same problem:
in my main page(index.js) I was put 
`app.set('trust proxy', 1);
app.use(session({ secret: 'gbcimsifre', resave: false, saveUninitialized: true, cookie: {} }));` code block after the app.use() middleware. Now I put this block before the middleware and problem solved. thanks for everybody.